# Is it possible to work with AWS Sagemaker Studio Notebooks using a local IDE?

Tags: jupyter, aws, sagemaker

Is it possible to work with AWS Sagemaker Studio Notebooks using an IDE such as VSCode or PyCharm/IntelliJ running on my local machine?
And if yes, how?

Ideally I'd like to want to connect to the Sagemaker-managed Jupyter kernel from my local IDE, so I can see and edit the notebook in my IDE while execution happens in the kernel on AWS Sagemaker.

I know how to connect to a self-managed Jupyter installation on a remote server like EC2. This is not want I want. I'm looking to connect to a kernel managed by Sagemaker Studio.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode supports a client-server architecture where the server is remote and the client is local. The process is to set up a Visual Studio Code Server on AWS and then connect that remote instance to your local VSCode client, step-by-step directions are [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/host-code-server-on-amazon-sagemaker/).

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a great approach, but (as of July 2023) has a severe limitation: You can only install it code server on the "system" instance of Sagemager Studio, not on the (poentially bigger) instances that run the Jupyter notebook kernels. Option B only seems to work on non-Studio instances.
(see sofian's comment below the post you linked to and https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-codeserver/issues/10 ) 
So that doesn't really solve the question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The only approach that I have found to work is to use the [sagemaker-ssh-helper](https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker-ssh-helper/). This uses AWS SSM + SSH along with VSCode's remote development extension.